# ASP.net page_load doesn't detect session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with using `session` variable in the `page_load`. I have a page (`members.aspx`) which is a members area.

If the user isn't `logged` in, it will display a form asking them to login. The form submits their details, checks if ok then sets `session` variables if `OK`. It then reloads the page.

So if the user has authenticated correctly, it sets `Session["memberLoggedIn"] = true`. 
My `page_load` function then looks like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["memberLoggedIn"]) == true) {
        Response.Write("OK");
    }
}
```

There is more code, but essentially, the "OK" should be written. However, it doesn't appear. Even though the `session` IS set. If I go to the page directly it will then show. It's just for the reloading of the members page from the initial login which stops it.

any ideas?!

======================
the code to set the session is

```
if (logindetails.Count > 0) {
    System.Data.DataRow details = logindetails[0];
    Session["memberLoggedIn"] = true;
}
```

I then just check if `(Convert.ToBoolean(Session["memberLoggedIn"]) == true)` on all my pages. To be honest it doesn't seem that reliable and I Think sometimes I need to understand the order in which pages are loaded as when I destroy the session on the log out page, some parts still show the logged in features! (but that's another story....)

Comment: Do you mean it's when the page refreshes after the actual login process that you don't see the "OK"?

Comment: yes that's correct. If I were to login, then go to another page and then back to the members home page, it shows. Just not after the reload.

Comment: Let's see the code for setting the Session.

Comment: ok updated with session setup, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
            if(user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                 Session["memberLoggedIn"] = true;
                 Print();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["memberLoggedIn"]) == true)
            {
                Response.Write("ok");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like when you log in you are choosing whether to write "OK" before you have processed the login. In terms of the page's pipeline page_load is before your event handler that you are likely processing the login.

You have various options, the simplest of which could be to move this particular logic to Page_PreRender (if it makes sense to) as at this point your session variable will have been set.