# Stored Procedures unexpected behavior on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I am facing a strange behavior of data returned by stored procedures from the `Page_Load` function.

Here is code of `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["LoggedinUser"] != null)
    {
        loggedinUsername.Text = "Welcome " + Session["LoggedinUser"].ToString() + " ";
        logout.Visible = true;
        ArrayList Result1 = new ArrayList();
        ReservationPending_StandardUser RPU = new ReservationPending_StandardUser();
        Result1 = RPU.GetStandardUserSpaceReservationDetailsByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedinUserID"].ToString()));
        string SpaceID = Result1[0].ToString();
        string TransactionCode = Result1[1].ToString();
        int TRefID = Convert.ToInt32(Result1[2].ToString());
        Transaction_EasyPaisa EP = new Transaction_EasyPaisa();
        DataTable dt = EP.GetEasyPaisaTransaction(TRefID);
        string datetransaction = dt.Rows[0]["DateTimeStamp"].ToString();
        string _amountPaid = dt.Rows[0]["AmoutPaid"].ToString();
        spaceID.Text = SpaceID;
        dateReservation.Text = datetransaction;
        amountPaid.Text = _amountPaid;
        if (TransactionCode.Equals("EP"))
            paymentMethod.Text = "Easypaisa";
        status.Text = "Pending";

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

The two functions `GetStandardUserSpaceReservationDetailsByID` and `GetEasyPaisaTransaction` are actually retrieving data from respective stored procedures. The problem is sometimes they returns data and sometimes not.

Let me explain with a scenario:

I first load the page and it shows me the results. Then I refresh page and it shows empty data returned by either of above functions. Then I again refresh page and it retrieves data and this behavior goes on randomly.

Is this issue related to ASP.NET page lifecycle? If so please help to resolve because it will ruin my work done so far.

Comment: You should probably post the SPs, too.

Comment: Is SQL throwing any errors when you don't get data back?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? In particular, I would be interested to see the value of `Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedinUserID"].ToString())` when it succeeds and when it fails. You should also start to narrow down what "doesn't work" means. For instance, is `loggedinUsername` always set correctly?

Comment: In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with SPs. But when I refresh page then the page loads without retrieving the results. Is this possible?

Comment: Try this solution. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672393/asp-net-page-load-doesnt-detect-session

Comment: Also, trivial thing, but you don't need the `new ArrayList()` since you're about to overwrite it. Try `ReservationPending_StandardUser RPU = new ReservationPending_StandardUser();
        ArrayList Result1 =  RPU.GetStandardUserSpaceReservationDetailsByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedinUserID"].ToString()));`

Comment: You have to define which part doesn't work.  Does GetStandardUserSpaceReservationDetailsByID return an empty ArrayList?  Or null?  Or is an exception thrown?  Be specific.